# How to add a SwiftUI some View Type as a Requirement to an Protocol?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, functional-programming, protocols

**Context**

I have a `Protocol` and would like it to have a `SwiftUI` `some View` `Type` as one of its `Requirements`. I do know, that it is probably not the most elegant solution to mix the `Model` with the `View`, however, switching through all the different conforming `Types` each time I want to use the `View` isn't beautiful either.
Even though, I ran into a problem while implementing and got the following `Compiler Error`:

> 'some' type cannot be the return type of a protocol requirement; did you mean to add an associated type?

---

**Code**

```swift
protocol Component {
    var row: some View { get } // -> Compiler Error thrown in this Line.
}

// There are actually many more Types conforming to Component.
enum ComponentA: Component {
    var row: some View { 
        Text("Component A")
    }
}

struct ComponentsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(components) { component in
            component.row
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

How can I achieve my goal of only having to define the selection of the appropriate SwiftUI View once?

Comment: You have asked almost the same question a handful of times over the last few days. How is this different? The compiler is telling you what you are trying to do isn't possible it is giving you the alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could follow the same technique that Apple uses for `View` itself, which you can see by Command-clicking on a `View` reference in Xcode and selecting **Jump to Definition**.

```swift
protocol Component {
  associatedtype Body: View

  var row: Body { get }
}
```

As you declare some object's conformance to `Component`, the `row` autocomplete will automatically fill to `some View`:

[image: Screenshot of autocomplete for the row method]